# NodeJS Request filestream EMFILE error

Tags: windows, node.js, file, file-io

```
request.post({url: 'http://service.com/upload', form: {data: fs.createReadStream('T:/a.png')}});
```

After running this every second for ~10 minutes I get this error `Error: EMFILE` (too many open files)

Why? Am I supposed to be manually closing these streams? Why wouldn't `request` do that, but if so, how do I close them?

EDIT: I'm not making a lot of async calls, only 1 request is active at a time.

EDIT: No streams are ever being closed, it errors out exactly after I create 2046 streams. Why aren't they being closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, it depends on what kind of service you are building.

If, for an example, you are executing that `fs.createReadStream` many times async (like thousands of times in parallel), Node.JS will throw that error.

Try to debug your application like this (checking the number of opened streams).

```
var fs = require("fs");

var streams = 0;
var i;

try {
  for (i=0;i<10000;i++)
  {
    streams++;
    fs.createReadStream('./file.png').once('end',function () { streams--; });
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(streams);
}
```

Comment: I'm not doing a lot of async calls, only 1 request should be active at a time. Thank you for the debug code, that should help, I'll check it out when I can.

Comment: No streams are ever being closed, it errors out exactly after I create 2046 streams. Why aren't they being closed by `request`?

Comment: The ServerResponse's stream is closed 'automagically' by Node.JS.
The problem with your code (i think) is that you are opening file streams and not closing them anywhere. Try listening to the socket.on('close',function() {}) and closing the opened file stream.

Comment: what `socket`? And how do I even close a stream?

Comment: Socket from the http connection and stream of file. You can call stream.close()

Comment: `stream.close()` doesn't exist. But `stream.destory()` does, and it's all good now. thanks